# Use switch case and filter/find/loop through array of objects to filter and find the correct object to update JavaScript

Tags: javascript

What is the best way for me to filter through the below `columns` array of objects, select the correct `object` using my `switch` method, and set the `show` property to `false` (JavaScript)? This is the first time implementing something like this, and I am a a bit uncertain how to tackle this.

Example: if I pass 'Surname' to my `showHideSelectedColumn(column)` method, it filters the `columns` array, finds the `{name: 'Surname', show: true}` object, and sets this specific object's `show` property to false.

```
columns = [{name: 'Surname', show: true}, {name: 'Name', show: false}, {name: 'Gender', show: true}, {name: 'Date of Birth', show: false}, {name: 'ID/Passport Number', show: true}, {name: 'Membership Status', show: true}];

showHideSelectedColumn(column) {

switch (column) {
  case 'Surname':
    // set show = false
    break;
  case 'Name':
    // set show = false
    break;
  case 'Gender':
    // set show = false
    break;
  case 'Date of Birth':
    // set show = false;
    break;
  case 'ID/Passport Number':
    // set show = false
    break;
}
```

Comment: If you HAVE to use the `switch` then a loop or `forEach` can do it.

Comment: Awesome thanks. I have a bit of a challenge on how to update the 'show' parameter of the specific object. Any suggestions?

Comment: `column.show = false`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aternative and generic solution using **.find** method  . You need to pass the array and the column name to the method , it will return you the updated array setting show property of that column to be **false**

```js
var columns = [{name: 'Surname', show: true}, {name: 'Name', show: false}, {name: 'Gender', show: true}, {name: 'Date of Birth', show: false}, {name: 'ID/Passport Number', show: true}, {name: 'Membership Status', show: true}];

function setShow(array, column){

  var found = array.find(obj =>  obj.name===column);
  if(found){
    found.show = false;
  }
  return array;
}

console.log(setShow(columns,"Surname"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can map your array and if there is match you can toggle it by following example

```
Array.prototype.toggleProperty = function (property){
     return this.map(el=>{
         if(el.name===property){
             return {...el,show:!el.show}
         }
         else{
             return el
         }
     })
}
// test 

console.log(columns.toggleProperty("Name"))
```